# Javascript API user page coding style

Tags: javascript

I have Javascript source code that contain Jsonp API functions. Wherever this Javascript source code got printed I got to check first if the "api tag" printed already, if it did -> execute the API function, if the "api tag" have not got printed yet, wait for the tag to get printed on the screen and then execute the API functions.

For example, I have this code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- js code - contain Jsonp functions -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsonp.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- when this newtag get print , the function starts -->
    <newtag:api size="small">myNewTag</newtag:api>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't know where the user will decide to put the JS code, it may be in the head, body or in the middle of the page, since I have this mystery I can't do something like this:

```
<newtag:api size="small">myNewTag</newtag:api>
<script> startJsonp(); </script>
```

because if the js code did not print yet the order will not be execute.

- if the code got print in the head it will not work since the "api tag" did not got printed yet.
- to make the API work I need the "api tag" to be printed on the screen already for the Jsonp functions to work.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you wait until the window has finished loading?

```
<body onload='startJsonp();'>
```

Comment: it can take several seconds , in big website it can take even 30 seconds until the page finish load , sometime it take for ever so obviously , no! but thanks.